# Using 2 google forms linked to a single spreadsheet, determine which form just submitted a data and identify the data just submitted like column data

Tags: forms, triggers, spreadsheet, form-submit

I created an inquiry form and other form for updating and both are in a single spreadsheet, therefore I have 2 sheets handling the 2 forms. My question is, how can I identify which form just submitted a data and get the column number of the data just submitted using the form submit trigger? What condition should I use? Thank you so much for your help.

I have tried e.range.getsheet(); based on my research yet, it doesn't function